# Standard definition of a Tensor Algebra?

Tags: definition, tensors, universal-algebra

Let $M$ be a $R$-module. I know that the set of a tensor algebra is given by:

$$T(M)=\bigoplus_{k=0}^\infty T^k(M)$$

where $T^K(M)=M\otimes ...\otimes M$ ($k$ times). But I am confused about the *fundamental operations* defined along with this set (see the definition of an algebra given [here](http://www.math.hawaii.edu/~ralph/Classes/619/ALVin.pdf) (pg2) ). The three possible onces are:

1. Addition of tensors of the same rank.
2. Tensor product.
3. Multiplication by a scalar.

Different sources seem to include different combinations of these when defining a tensor  algebra (many don't even mention the operators). My question is; which operators do we, as standard, take when defining the tensor algebra? (sources would be helpful).

Comment: An algebra over a field needs all three operations: addition, multiplication, and scalar multiplication. So the answer is all three. (Some might consider scalar multiplication a side effect of having a field in the center and the multiplication operation being bilinear with respect to it.) Also, I would call these *operations*, not operators.

Comment: @anon I agree that a (bilinear) algebra over a field needs all three but cannot see how the tensor algebra in question relates to an algebra over a field?

Comment: The tensor algebra *is* an algebra over a field (at least when $R$ is taken to be a field, and $M$ is a vector space, otherwise it's an $R$-algebra). And the definition in the link you give is way, way, way too general - it is not talking about algebras over a field or $R$-algebras, it is talking about *any concrete algebraic structure at all* (including rings, groups, lattices, etc.) in the context of universal algebra, so not relevant to your question.

Comment: @anon "tensor algebra is an algebra over a field" is this by definition or a consequence of the definition of the tensor algebra? Concerning the link, it may be general but surly the a tensor algebra must be an algebra as defined by this general definition?

Comment: The tensor algebra is defined with operations that make it clearly an $R$-algebra. Sure, it fits under the general definition of the link, but so does almost every other concrete algebraic structure in all of mathematics. Not relevant to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like the name suggests, $T(M)$ should be a (graded, associative) $R$-algebra (with unit). This means one should describe quite a few structures on $T(M)$:

1. The set $T(M)$ should have the structure of an $R$-module. Hence, there should be an addition map $T(M) \times T(M) \rightarrow T(M)$ and a scalar multiplication map $R \times T(M) \rightarrow T(M)$ which are compatible with each other according to the axioms of an $R$-module. The addition should be defined between any two tensors, not only tensors of the same rank (or even homogeneous tensors).
2. The set $T(M) = \bigoplus_{k=0}^{\infty} T^k(M)$ has a grading given by the direct sum.
3. The set $T(M)$ should have an $R$-bilinear multiplication operation $T(M) \times T(M) \rightarrow T(M)$ which gives it the structure of an $R$-algebra. This multiplication is associative, has a unit and respects the grading. On homogeneous and elementary tensors, it is given by 
   $$(m_1 \otimes \cdots \otimes m_k) \cdot (w_1 \otimes \cdots \otimes w_l) = m_1 \otimes \cdots \otimes m_k \otimes w_1 \otimes \cdots \otimes w_l. $$

This is quite tedious to do in full detail so often enough textbooks assume the reader is mature enough to fill in the details behind all those structures.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How are you defining a $R$-algebra here? In Dummit and Foote (2004;pg342) they define it as a ring, $A$, with identity and a homomorphism $f:R \rightarrow A$ such that $1_R$ maps to $1_A$ and the subring $f(R)$ is in the center of $A$. This seems to be inconsistent with how you (and actually how Dummit and Foote later on) define it in terms of a $R$-bilinear multiplication operator. Also why *should* $T(M)$ have the structure of an $R$-module? Could it not just be a ring?

Comment: @Quantumspaghettification: See the first page of http://people.virginia.edu/~mve2x/7752_Spring2010/lecture5.pdf. Each piece $T^k(M)$ is an $R$-module and the direct sum of $R$-modules is an $R$-module.